# Is convolution of a distribution with a function defined?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

I know how the convolution of a distribution is defined. But when my teacher defined the Hilbert transform of a $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\Bbb R)\cap L^1(\Bbb R)$ as
$$
Hf(x):=\frac1{\pi}\operatorname{p.v.}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac1s f(x-s)\,ds
$$
he said that $Hf$ is the convolution between $f$ and $\frac1{\pi}\operatorname{p.v.}\frac1x$, where $\operatorname{p.v.}\frac1x$,is the distribution which sends
$$
\phi\mapsto\operatorname{p.v.}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac1x\phi(x)\,dx\;\;.
$$
Did I misunderstood my teacher? Or maybe there exists a definition of the convolution between a function and a distribution?

Many thanks

Comment: A (sufficiently regular) function can be seen as a distribution.

Comment: @CaptainLama: I'm a very very beginner with distribution. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: Maybe you mean that given $f\in L^1_{\mbox{loc}}(\Bbb R)$ I can consider the so called regular distribution $T_f$, which sends $\phi\mapsto\int_{\Bbb R}f\phi$.

Am I right?

Comment: If $f$ is a function that is locally $L^1$ (in your case you have much better since your $f$ is both $L^1$ and $\mathcal{C}^1$), then you can define the distribution $\phi\mapsto \int f(x)\phi(x)dx$. It is the distribution defined by $f$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Look at Rudin *Functional Analysis* 6.27-6.37 for a discussion of convolutions of functions and distributions.  Doubtless there is a similar discussion in other books with good coverage of distributions.